# ¿Cómo se traza una ruta desde la ubicación actual a un marcador dentro de una Google Map Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocalización

Lo que quiero hacer es trazar una ruta en un GoogleMap Activity de Android desde el la ubicación actual del usuario hasta un marcador de destino. Sólo he conseguido el primer paso el cual es la ubicación actual y colocar otro marcador, pero no logro hacer que se trace la ruta.

Aquí está mi código:

```
public class Trazo_Rutas extends FragmentActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
Location lastLocation;
Marker userLocation;
private static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trazo__rutas);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkUserLocationPermission();
    }

    //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
    if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    }

    //AutoComplete search bar
    placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
    placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    0).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    //get latlng for corners for specified place
    LatLng corner1 = new LatLng(25.64379, -103.60966);
    LatLng corner2 = new LatLng(25.64317, -103.20935);
    LatLng corner3 = new LatLng(25.43872, -103.61104);
    LatLng corner4 = new LatLng(25.43748, -103.20866);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    builder.include(corner1);
    builder.include(corner2);
    builder.include(corner3);
    builder.include(corner4);

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    //add them to builder
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    // 20% padding
    int padding = (int) (width * 0.20);

    //set latlng bounds
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds);

    //move camera to fill the bound to screen
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));

    //set zoom to level to current so that you won't be able to zoom out viz. move outside bounds
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                markerPoints.clear();
                mMap.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(latLng);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(latLng);

            if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            mMap.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                LatLng origin = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }

        }
    });

}

public boolean checkUserLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, Request_User_Location_Code);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, Request_User_Location_Code);
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_User_Location_Code:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (googleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }

                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se requieren Permisos de Google", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            return;
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;

    if (userLocation != null) {
        userLocation.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    markerOptions.title("Tu ubicación");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

    userLocation = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        String data = "";

        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsParser parser = new DirectionsParser();

            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(25);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            lineOptions.geodesic(true);

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String mode = "mode=driving";
    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode;
    // Output format
    String output = "json";
    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
}`
```

Este código contiene dos marcadores, pero quiero que uno de ellos sea la ubicación actual. ¿Cómo lo logro?

Comment: te refieres a :  LatLng origin = (LatLng) markerPoints.get()} ?

Comment: probé con 2 markerPoints aparte de mi ubicación actual. Lo que quiero hacer es reemplazar el markerPoint de origen por la ubicación actual al mismo tiempo que se trace la ruta hacia donde ponga el makerPoint de destino

Answer (score 0):

para dibujar una ruta en un mapa vas a necesitar 2 cosas, primero la ruta en si, eso lo obtenes pidiendosela a la api de google usando una url como esta:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&departure_time=now&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

dentro del json de la respuesta encontraras esto:

```
"routes":{
   "overview_polyline" : {
      "points" : "yhd}@madqMD]CiA]..."//Es largisimo e ilegible pero es la ruta que debes dibujar
   }
}
```

el contenido de points lo podes desencodear con esto:

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng(((double) lat / 1E5),
                 ((double) lng / 1E5));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Y ya que tenes la ruta como un array de puntos solo tenes que imprimir el polyline en el mapa de esta forma:

```
private void addPolyline(List<LatLng> points){
   PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();   
   polylineOptions.addAll(points);
   polylineOptions.width(10);
   polylineOptions.color(Color.argb(200,0,128,255));
   mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

te dejo tambien el [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) a la documentacion de google para que uses el request que mas te convenga.